# Why is the () included when calling some class functions?

Tags: kotlin, random

Here is my example:

```
fun randomDay() : String {
    val days = arrayOf("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")
    return days[Random().nextInt(3)]
}
```

How come it is `Random().nextInt(3)` and not `Random.nextInt(3)`?

Comment: There is no `new` keyword in Kotlin. So the `()` means either a function call or a constructor call. In your case `Random()` mean `new Random()` in Java. While `Random.nextInt(3)` would mean a static function call (from java), Kotlin `object` method call or a `companion object` method call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using methods of `java.util.Random` class you need to create an instance of that class. An instance of the class in Kotlin is created using **NameOfClass()** syntax. So to use `nextInt(3)` method of `Random` firstly you create an instance of that class `Random()` and then call `nextInt(3)` on created instance. So the whole code looks like this:

```
Random().nextInt(3)
```

**EDIT:**

Actually in Kotlin you can use two types of `Random` classes - `java.util.Random` and `kotlin.random.Random`. If you use `Random` class from `java.util` package you need to create an instance of `Random` class:

```
java.util.Random().nextInt()
```

If you use `Random` class from `kotlin.random` package you don't need to create an instance of the class:

```
kotlin.random.Random.nextInt()
```